# Programming an old school microcontroller (MSM80C49 from OKI semiconductor)

Tags: microcontroller, programming, assembly

I've read the whole [datasheet](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/1988OKIMicrocontrollerDataBook.737844695/view), there's no typical guidance on programming procedure/setup/circuitry.

It just mentions a few steps on how to order pre-programmed chips. (I guess) on page 18.

On a version of datasheet, it mentions a development tool called EASE80C49, and development softwares EASE49 & ASM49

A quick search didn't help me find any info on these tools and softwares.

These chips are very cheap.
How can I program them?

Comment: Are you sure those chips have internal programmable memory?

Comment: Datasheet says, for this part number,  ROM is 2K words 8bit, and RAM is 128 words 8bit. Doesn't this mean it's programmable?

Comment: Found on [MSM80C49 on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/293938022839) for $1.77 each chip, vs. the [ATTINY1604 at Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/ATTINY1604-SSN/10270322) for $0.81 each chip. And the programming tools are plenty for the ATTINY family vs. none that you found for the MSM80C49. Is there a real constraint to use the MSM80C49 vs. a modern chip?

Comment: The 80c49 doesn't include any built-in EPROM, only mask ROM.  [The mask ROM must be burned in the factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory#Factory_programmed). That's why you only see how to order pre-programmed chips for production after developing with the development kit.

Comment: @brhans The datasheet specifically says "mask ROM".

Comment: @icodeplenty strange, cheapest attiny where i live, (no online order) is 10x more expensive than the oki microcontroller which is under 20 cents (converted currencies).  Anyway thanks.

Comment: Didn't know what a mask rom is from the start. Now another question is why are these chips sold then (if they need to be programmed before buying) ?

Comment: @Elementronics They're sold because somebody has them.  Not only programmed before buying, but programmed *as part of manufacturing*.  I don't know if there's any way to tell which customer they were made for.  They might be programmed for some vintage consumer or industrial product that a buyer wants to repair.

Comment: You can run external eprom on them but you'd need an eprom chip and programmer. Any perceived savings have just evaporated right there. I know of a few companies that designed their product around this chip as they could obtain them for cents. Realistically, if you want to play with microcontrollers then get yourself an Arduino.

Comment: Note these chips were popular for use in PC keyboards. There's a fair chance the code inside is for a keyboard. If you tie the /EA pin low, it will try to execute code from an external eprom. These chips were predominantly programmed in assembler - there's no C compiler I'm aware of.  The chip is a second source of the Intel MCS48 series. Common part numbers are: 8048,8049,8050,8748,8749,8041,8042,8741,8742 and CMOS like the one you mention. These chips were second sourced by a number of companies. The MCS48 was superseded by the MCS51 series (8051). This architecture survives today.

Comment: If you can find the 8**7**49 (instead of 8**0**49), that would typically be the UV-EPROM version. These were a lot more expensive because it comes in a ceramic package with a quartz window for the ultraviolet light to erase the memory. At one point in the 1990s, there were OTP (one-time programmable) versions of these chips sold in cheaper plastic DIP packages, same IC chip but cannot be erased because they don't have the quartz window. About 1/3 the price.

Comment: 8049 is OTP version of 8749 (EPROM) version. intel had assembler and PLM compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Putting my comments into an answer for posterity)

This type of microcontroller was intended for large volume production, so they are not programmable after manufacturing.  The program is contained in [mask ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory#Factory_programmed) which was custom fabricated based on the customer's supplied code using a custom printed [photomask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomask).  The program was literally etched onto the silicon.  This had a high startup cost to create the mask, but very low manufactured unit cost.

I imagine the development kit circuit board would have included a version of the microcontroller whose ROM contained a only bootloader to run whatever code was being developed from an external EEPROM memory.

The ones you see as "new old stock" for sale are probably programmed with the firmware for some consumer or industrial product of the era.  It would be difficult or impossible to make use of them outside their original environment.